# Using sqlite3 How to set the width of one column in a SQL-db (or its CSV)

Tags: sql, database, csv, width

Getting desperate at this:

I try to limit the width of one particular column in a SQL-table to be 7 characters wide. More precisely, I would like to trim each element in the column to be a Text-element of at most 7 characters in width (if longer, it shall be truncated).

Another possibility is to alter the number of characters in the corresponding CSV column before SQL-db creation.

The problem: The DB is large !!

(And therefore altering the CSV (before SQL-DB creation) is not possible with most common tools such as Sublime, Atom, or Excel)

What alternatives are there ? (maybe sqlite3 or some terminal-cmd ??)

My CSV-File (`table1.txt`) looks like:

```
some_text,some_id,stop_name
"Hello World1","1101069:0:1","MyName1"
"Hello World2","1333332","MyName2"
"Hello World3","1452339:0","MyName3"
"Hello World4","8334342:2:0","MyName4"
```

The some_id column shall be restricted to 7 characters, resulting in...

```
some_text,some_id,stop_name
"Hello World1","1101069","MyName1"
"Hello World2","1333332","MyName2"
"Hello World3","1452339","MyName3"
"Hello World4","8334342","MyName4"
```

My sqlite3 creation file (`creationFile.sql`) looks like that:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (some_text TEXT PRIMARY KEY, some_id TEXT, stop_name TEXT) WITHOUT ROWID;

.separator ,
.import table1.txt table1
```

I use the following sqlite3 terminal cmd to create the DB :

```
sqlite3 myTable.db > creationFile.sql`
```

Now again, the column-width restriction could already be introduced in the CSV-file. But I think this is rather impossible since no standard editor does it anymore due to the large size of the CSV-file (> 10 Mio lines). Is there a way sqlite3 can handle this during DB creation ? Or any terminal cmd doing so before, during or after DB creation ??

Comment: `left(<your string>, 7)` or equivalent. That depends on the DBMS you're working with (which is?).

Comment: Thanks. I am working with DB-Browser for SQLite (Mac OS). And I create the DB with sqlite3 terminal cmd from a CSV-file

Comment: Consider to edit your question and add the appropriate sqlite tags then. For SQLite the equivalent would be `substr(<your string>, 1, 7)`. You need to apply this to the values before inserting them into the table. I cannot tell you how you have do that exactly, as I don't know the program you use there. But maybe you can figure this out yourself and that mere hint is valuable anyways.

Comment: I added more information on the creation process of the DB. Can you please tell me a bit more in detail on how and where I would add your `substr(<your string>, 1, 7)` exactly ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. After creating **table1** run this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS
  SELECT some_text, SUBSTR(some_id, 1, 7) as some_id, stop_name
  FROM table1;
```

Note: not sure about syntax of SUBSTR() function. It's better to google it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the most efficient way, but as I don't know the tool, the only one I can see:

1. Create your database and import all the data with the full text length. As your column types are `text` that should work for any text length.
2. After that, update the table to trim the texts. For example, if the text you want to shorten is the text of the column `stop_name_text`:

   ```
   UPDATE table1
          SET stop_name_text = substr(stop_name_text, 1, 7);
   ```

   But  be careful, when you want to do that to `some_text`: You declared that as `PRIMARY KEY`. The shortening might result in two identical texts in different columns. E.g. if you have "Hello World" and "Hello Walter" both will result in "Hello W". The values of a column declared `PRIMARY KEY` must be unique though, so the `UPDATE` will fail in such a case.

   Or maybe that was a mistake and you wanted to actually declare `some_id`as `PRIMARY KEY`? The name suggests that.

Comment: thank you for your help. My final solution went with maxim's solution - not because his is much better than yours but because of the reason you mentioned with the primary-key !!